# javascript background cookie

Tags: javascript, cookies

I'm trying to write two functions to set and get a cookie that save the user favorite background-color :

```
function set_background_cookie(){
if ( navigator.cookieEnabled )  {
    favColor = window.prompt( "insert your favorite color please : " , "") ;
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = favColor ;
    document.cookie = "favoriteColor=" + favColor + ";" + "expires=Sat, 25 Apr 2020 12:11:05 GMT" ;
    }
}

function get_background_cookie(){
var start , End , color ;
var CookiesArray = document.cookie.split(';') ;
start = CookiesArray[0].indexOf('=');
End = start + CookiesArray.length ;
color = CookiesArray[0].substring(start + 1 , End ) ;
document.body.style.backgroundColor = color ;
}
```

setting the cookie is perfect but I have a problem with getting it 
what was my problem ??

this is the whole page :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head> 

<script> 

function get_background_cookie(){
var start , End , color ;
var CookiesArray = document.cookie.split(';') ;
start = CookiesArray[0].indexOf('=');
End = start + CookiesArray.length ;
color = CookiesArray[0].substring(start + 1 , End ) ;
document.body.style.backgroundColor = color ;
}

function set_background_cookie(){
if ( navigator.cookieEnabled )  {
    favColor = window.prompt( "insert your favorite color please : " , "") ;
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = favColor ;
    document.cookie = "favoriteColor=" + favColor + ";" + "expires=Sat, 25 Apr 2020 12:11:05 GMT" ;
    }
}

window.onload = function(){
set_background_cookie();
get_background_cookie();
}




</script>





</head>

<body>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
End = start + CookiesArray[0].length;
```

instead of:

```
End = start + CookiesArray.length ;
```

You should probably also check that the cookie exists instead of just assuming the cookie exists. Otherwise you could get JavaScript errors if the user has disabled cookies. Something like this should do the trick:

```
function get_background_cookie() {
    if (!document.cookie || !document.cookie.length)
        return;
    var CookiesArray = document.cookie.split(';');
    var start = CookiesArray[0].indexOf('=');
    var End = start + CookiesArray[0].length;
    var color = CookiesArray[0].substring(start + 1 , End );
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = color;
}
```